# java regex loop are not running properly

Tags: java, regex, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter no. of times input numbers will be given : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int index = 0, index1 = 0;
        int girl[] = new int[1000];
        int boy[] = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            String s = sc.next();
            Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
            Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher(s);
            while (mymatcher.find()) {
                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    girl[index] = Integer.valueOf(mymatcher.group());
                    index++;
                } else {
                    boy[index1] = Integer.valueOf(mymatcher.group());
                    index1++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            System.out.print(girl[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Why loop are not running upto its limit?

Comment: Can you add a brief description of what this code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also what it's actually doing.

Comment: *upto its limit* ? What is the output you get and what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: actually i want to run loop for n times for which i want to write something in string and using regex i want to match whether it contain integer or not.while taking n=2 i don,t able to write anything in string, means loop is not running.....

Comment: @ShubhamKumar - did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop runs correctly for the no. of times i.e. n.

You should format your code, Java class name should be CamelCase and without underscore and do add System.out.println to help you understand debugging and program makes more logical sense.

It seems like your program is expecting a number for which user can enter numbers.

There are 2 arrays i.e. girl and boy. If the number is odd then then it is added to girl array and if the number is even then it is added to boy array.

Finally girl array is printed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter no. of times input numbers will be given : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int index = 0, index1 = 0;
        int girl[] = new int[1000];
        int boy[] = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            String s = sc.next();
            Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
            Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher(s);
            while (mymatcher.find()) {
                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    girl[index] = Integer.valueOf(mymatcher.group());
                    index++;
                } else {
                    boy[index1] = Integer.valueOf(mymatcher.group());
                    index1++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            System.out.print(girl[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
Enter no. of times input numbers will be given : 
4
10
11
12
13
10 12
```